# How to uninstall Python from pip

Tags: apt, package-management, python, pip

My default Python installation is from pip which is at 2.7.10. `apt-get` has already Python 2.7.13 installed. I don't want to keep both installations because it's confusing, and I would prefer to keep the `apt-get` one because I'm more familiar with it. Can pip use the Python installation from `apt-get`?
Trying to uninstall pip Python, I get:

```
pedro@gordo-002528460857:~$ pip uninstall python
Cannot uninstall 'Python'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

What's the best way to work this out?
If you have any better advice, I'm happy to take it because I don't work regularly with Python, so I don't know the best practices here.

**EDIT:**
This is how I see that the 2.7.10 is from `pip` and not from `apt-get`:
[image]

**EDIT 2*:**
More info from the .bashrc:

```
export PATH="~/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

And also:

```
pedro@gordo-002528460857:~$ which pip
/home/pedro/.pyenv/shims/pip
```

Comment: Does `pip list` list both python installations? Try uninstalling with specific version like `pip uninstall python==2.7.10`

Comment: That uninstall command didn't work (same error I get). Running `pip list` doesn't show any python version on the list. What does that mean?

Comment: Sorry I drifted away earlier, you can't install python with pip :-p . So back to the initial question, how did you install the python version 2.7.10, was it built from source code?

Comment: @beginer I can't remember lol... :) How can I figure that out?

Comment: hehe alright so what is the exact problem? How do you know you have python 2.7.10 installed alongside 2.7.13 ?

Comment: @beginer added in post :)

Comment: `apt-get` has Python >2.7.12, and `pip` has 2.7.10.

Comment: Aahaa, its just the pip, but strange how could that be. Alright it seems you have modified your $PATH. You see in the output it says `Location: /home/pedro...........`, that means the output of `pip show` is from a virtualenv. But the strange thing is that you don't have a virtualenv prompt. Try this `which pip`, I bet it would be the same /home path. Check your .bashrc file if it has a modified $PATH

Comment: @beginer indeed it had (check post EDIT 2)! Should I just remove those 3 lines then, to use the Python installation of `apt-get`?

Comment: yes remove those lines. I'll right an answer so that you can upvote and select as correct answer :-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation info you get from `pip show python` is actually a python virtualenv created by you or someone else into the path `~/.pyenv/bin:$PATH` and was added to bashrc so that it gets loaded by default at login. So the solution is to delete those lines from `.bashrc` and re-login, then you'll only see and be able to use the system python version. If you want to use that virtualenv then run the command `source ~/.pyenv/bin/activate` and then to exit: `deactivate`

At the moment that virtualenv was created, the system python version was `2.7.10`, hence the version shown by pip. Later the system python was upgraded thats why you see a latest version with `apt-get` now. Upgrading the system python doesn't affect virtualenv, you need to rebuild it if required. There is a good discussion on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218946/upgrade-python-in-a-virtualenv)